# mkdir multiple subfolders in bash script

Tags: bash, mkdir

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/parentfolder/{child_1,child_2}"
mkdir -p $path
mkdir -p /parentfolder/{child_3,child_4}
```

Running it creates the following folders:

```
/parentfolder/{child_1,child_2}
/parentfolder/child_3
/parentfolder/child_4
```

How can I make the script create the following folder structure:

```
/parentfolder/child_1
/parentfolder/child_2
/parentfolder/child_3
/parentfolder/child_4
```

Comment: The manual explains how [shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) work.  Brace expansion occurs before parameter (variable) expansion, so the braces in the parameter value are not expanded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use brace expansion in a quoted variable; either put the braces in the command itself, or assign the variable differently. If you need the values to be in a variable, using an array would seem suitable.

```
#!/bin/bash

paths=(/parentfolder/{child_1,child_2,child_3,child_4})
mkdir -p "${paths[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path=`echo /parentfolder/{child_1,child_2}`
```

expansion needs a command to work properly.